# Best way to sort a list of lines for connectivity

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting

I have a long list of lines in (possibly) random order.  So basically:

```
struct Line
{
  Vector StartPos;
  Vector EndPos;
};
```

Now I'm looking for an efficient way to sort these lines so that they are sorted into spans.  I.E. if line A's startpos matches Line B's endpos, it gets moved into the list immediately after line B.  If nothing matches, it just goes to the end of the list to start a new span.

Right now I'm doing it brute force-- setting a flag variable if anything was changed, and if anything changed, sorting it again.  This produces gigantically exponential iterations.  Is there any faster way to optimize this so that I could conceivably keep the iterations down to listsize^listsize?

Comment: You didn't mention of these "lines" can overlap. If so, how are overlaps processed?  At any rate, it seems simplest to start by sorting according to start position.  Then it's easy to scan the list and find spans. If there are overlaps, you'll want a second list of references sorted by end position. Then you can process the pair of lists as "events" in the manner of a 1d "scan line algorithm."  You can look that up for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have lines that start or end at the same point maybe you can use dictionaries to reduce the look ups. Something like:

```
    public class Line
    {
        public Point StartPos;
        public Point EndPos;
        public bool isUsed = false;
    };
```

and then 1) create a dictionary with the key the endPos and the value the index of the element in you list, 2) for each element of the list follow the link using the dictionary. Something like:

```
    List<List<Line>> result = new List<List<Line>>();
    Dictionary<Point,int> dic= new Dictionary<Point,int>();
    for (int kk = 0; kk < mylines.Count; kk++)
    {
        dic[mylines[kk].EndPos] = kk;
    }
    for (int kk = 0; kk < mylines.Count; kk++)
    {
        if (mylines[kk].isUsed == false)
        {
            var orderline= new List<Line>();   
            orderline.Add(mylines[kk]);

            int mm = kk;
            while (dic.ContainsKey(mylines[mm].EndPos))
            {
                mm = dic[mylines[mm].EndPos];
                mylines[mm].isUsed = true;
                orderline.Add(mylines[mm]);
            }

            result.Add(orderline);
        }
    }
```